# How to animate control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, controls

I've seen a sample WPF program that I cannot find. In this sample when I click a button another button starts growing and shrinking. Mean while I can do other stuff with the form. How do I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Below you will find a very simple example of a button height\width growing when the button is clicked and shrinking back when the mouse leaves the control. Animation in WPF is done by using StoryBoards. Storyboards are typically found in EventTriggers and can be saved in the resouces of the control,window, page, or application. Below is the sample along with some resources:

```
<Window x:Class="WPFFeatureSample_Application.AnimationWindowSample"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="AnimationWindowSample" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Sample" Width="50" Height="50">
        <Button.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="200" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"></DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="200" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"></DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="50" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"></DoubleAnimation>
                        <DoubleAnimation To="50" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"></DoubleAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Button.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx

http://windowsclient.net/learn/

Answer (score 1):

You can animate controls in WPF using a Storyboard.

Check out the [Animation Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312.aspx) on MSDN.